# Loop over elements in jQuery when element is double clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and Javascript.  I'm trying to make a button that I can double click which then loops through all elements in the webpage with a certain class and fades them.

Currently, I'm trying this:

```
$(".fadeall").dblclick(function() {
    $("div.section").each(function(idx,item) {
        item.fadeTo(25,inactiveOpacity);
    });
});
```

In my debugger I see the double click happening, but the function in the `each` call is not being triggered.

I'm believe I'm not matching the `div.section` elements correctly, but don't know the correct approach.

Comment: What do your `div.section` elements look like?  They should be `<div class="section">` (or may have additional classes as well).

Comment: @Nick Usually they are <div class="section"> but sometimes there are other classes.  Does that matter?

Comment: @Rich - Nope, as long as one of those classes is `section` then it'll work.

Comment: @Rich - You also need to make sure the DOM is ready before your code runs. If the elements haven't loaded, the selector will not find any matches. See the EDIT at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: ...also, I should probably ask if the `div.section` elements were added to the DOM dynamically, or if they were present when the page loaded?

Comment: @patrick - Why would it matter for *those* elements? ;) They're selected at the time of the event :)

Comment: @Nick - Yes, of course. It would not matter for those. Just the `.fadeall`. Good point. :o)

Comment: After this question is answered, is there a performance benefit by using either the passed variable in `each` (item) or use `$(this)` ?

Comment: @adardesign - There isn't, they're both present, I just *personally* find `this` a bit cleaner if you're not in need of the index, but either work (and perform) equally well.

Comment: @Nick and @patrick.  Thanks for the help.  Later I just removed the .each call and did a plain $("div.section").fadeTo(...).  As I said, I'm just learning jQuery and JavaScript.  I get now that every time the $(..) operator is encountered it returns a set of those items.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the HTML has `<div>` elements with the class `section`, the only other thing I can see that you would need to do is wrap `item` in a jQuery object.

```
$(".fadeall").dblclick(function() {
    $("div.section").each(function(idx,item) {
           // Wrapped "item" so you have access to jQuery methods
        $(item).fadeTo(25,inactiveOpacity);
    });
});
```

Since `item` is the DOM element, it needs to be wrapped with a jQuery object so that it will have access to methods like `.fadeTo()`.

Another approach is to use `this` in the `.each()`, which will refer to the DOM element as well.

```
$(".fadeall").dblclick(function() {
    $("div.section").each(function() {
           // Wrapped "this" so you have access to jQuery methods
        $(this).fadeTo(25,inactiveOpacity);
    });
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

Also, make sure the DOM is loaded before your code runs:

```
   // Wrapping code like this ensures that the DOM elements will be
   //    loaded before your code runs.
$(function() {
    $(".fadeall").dblclick(function() {
        $("div.section").each(function() {
               // Wrapped "this" so you have access to jQuery methods
            $(this).fadeTo(25,inactiveOpacity);
        });
    });
});
```

This is  a shortcut for [jQuery's `.ready()` method](http://api.jquery.com/ready), which will ensure that your code doesn't run until the elements are available.

Answer (score 4):

It should be erroring out since the DOM element doesn't have a [`.fadeTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) function, you need to wrap the element you're looping over (`item`) in a jQuery object, like this:

```
$(item).fadeTo(25,inactiveOpacity);
```

Or, `this` works as well, for example:

```
$(".fadeall").dblclick(function() {
  $("div.section").each(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(25,inactiveOpacity);
  });
});
```